# How to reset GTM data layer in android?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, google-datalayer

I am integrating GTM in my Android Application. In documentation I can see following caution:

Caution: Because the data layer is persistent, reset transaction and item variable values to null after you've pushed a transaction to the data layer.

I am finding some methods to reset datalayer in javascript but there seems to be no method to reset datalayer in android. How to do this?

Problem is, I am currently pushing Product Detail Views, Add to Cart, Remove from Cart and Purchases. At first I was getting Product Detail Views and no other event. On diabling the call for Product Detail View, I started getting records for Add to Cart and after disabling Add to cart, transactions are reflecting on Google Analytics. In this scenario, my understanding is resetting the datalayer after each push can help me.

One more thing, I am getting Add to Cart and Remove from Cart as events on google analytics but they are not reflecting on Shopping Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As in caution we have to replace all the item variables values to null and push the datalayer again after every transaction.

Example : Let's see Pushing Event to the dataLayer

```
String eventName = "productClick";
Map<String, Object> dataMap = DataLayer.mapOf(
    "ecommerce", DataLayer.mapOf(
        "click", DataLayer.mapOf(
            "actionField", DataLayer.mapOf(
                "list", "Search Results"),
            "products", DataLayer.listOf(
                DataLayer.mapOf(
                    "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt",
                    "id", "12345",
                    "price", "15.25",
                    "brand", "Google",
                    "category", "Apparel",
                    "variant", "Gray")))));

//Get the datalayer singleton
DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
//Push event with datalayer
dataLayer.pushEvent(eventName, dataMap);
```

As you complete the transaction next is to clear the transaction data

```
  Map<String, Object> clearMap = new HashMap<>();
  // get the last data map 
  Iterator mapIterator = dataMap.entrySet().iterator(); // Iterator with dataMap item variables
  while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
    String key = (String) pair.getKey();
    clearMap.put(key, null);  //Setting item variables values to null
  }
  datLayer.push(clearMap);
```

This worked for me, you can try this.

And coming to data flow to GA it completely depends upon the configuration you did on Google TagManager.

Please follow GTM android documentation for configuration and other steps.